Formalizing the "maximum weight" problem
tl;rd How to generalize the fact that the shape of Earth which maximizes your weight is one in which all points on the boundary of Earth contribute the same?
My favorite physics question (credit here) is:

Assume the Earth is made of a fixed amount of a homogeneous, constant-density clay. You stand at the North Pole and can reshape the Earth under your feet. What shape of the Earth maximizes your weight?

Intuitively: to maximize your weight you want Earth-clay to be as close to you as possible, because gravitational force decreases with distance. But because it is fixed density, some must "spill out to the side" and thus its gravitational force will have a lateral component which does not contribute to your weight. The weight-maximizing solution balances these two effects.
I like to present the optimal shape as a series of arguments from symmetry:

There is a solution which is rotationally symmetric around the North-South pole axis, so we can work in 2D. (I hand-wave this; it just seems obvious).
The solution has no holes. For if there were a hole in the Earth, you could increase your weight by taking clay from the South Pole and moving it into the hole. (Again, seems obvious). Therefore our shape may be described by its boundary alone.
(The big idea) All points on the boundary must contribute the SAME gravitational force. By way of contradiction, assume some boundary point contributes a larger force than some other. But gravity is continuous, so we can increase our weight by digging up some clay from the weak area and placing it in the strong area. Therefore ALL points on the boundary contribute the SAME.

Now we're done: there are no holes, the force from the boundary is constant (say C), and we can just plug it into the gravitational force (constants dropped):
$$ C = \frac{\cos(\theta)}{r^2} $$
and just solve for r as a function of theta:
$$ r = \sqrt{\frac{\cos(\theta)}{C}} $$
It's just a polar equation! And (AFAIK) this shape has no name but is kind of a squashed sphere
(added a phase shift so the poles are on the vertical axis):
My questions:

How can we formalize argument 3? What is the best way to formalize the "dig up some clay" argument?
How can we generalize argument 3? "All boundary points contribute the same" feels like stationary action, or the optimum having zero derivative: can this be placed into the language of calculus of variations, or something else? Is this Lagrangian physics sneaking in?

Thank you for all answers.

You mention calculus of variations. I think this type of problem does not lend itself to application of calculus of variations.

As example of application of calculus of variation I take the catenary problem.
To solve for the shape of the catenary you have to set up a differential equation that has the catenary as solution. The solution: the shape of the catenary is described by the hyperbolic cosine function.
For application of calculus of variations the following property is crucial: every subsection of the curve is in and of itself an instance of the problem.
In the case of a catenary: take the hanging chain and make that two instances of the catenary problem by making an arbitrary point along the curve an additional point of suspension. Making that point an additional point of suspension doesn't change the shape; it's a static shape.
So now you have two subsections, and each has a shape according to the hyperbolic cosine function, just different subsections of the hyperbolic cosine function curve.
You can keep subdividing like that: every subsection of the catenary problem is an instance of the catenary problem, down to infinitesimally short subsections.
To solve the catenary problem: treat it as a concatenation of infinitesimally small subsections of the catenary problem.
Notably: the Euler-Lagrange equation is a differential equation. The Euler-Lagrange equation is a differential equation because the problem is addressed at the level of differentials.
In fact, the first time the catenary problem was solved was by Leibniz, half a century before the introduction of calculus of variations; Leibniz used a directly differential approach.
There is a Youtube video by Daniel Rubin, titled 'The Catenary (Hanging chain), how it was first solved'. (discussion of the contribtion by Leibniz starts at 19:12)
General statement about Calculus of Variations:
Calculus of Variations is applicable when the problem can be solved with a differential equation. Calculus of Variations is a technique to arrive at a differential equation that will solve the problem.

The 'maximize gravitational pull' problem doesn't seem to have that every-subsection-is-an-instance-of-the-problem property. So I expect it cannot be addressed with calculus of variations.



I think argument 3 is already in its most general form.
Let me make a comparison: the wobbly table theorem
A table with four legs of even length is on an uneven surface. Let the respective table legs be referred to as A, B, C and D.
There is an initial state where the table wobbles. The diagonally opposed legs A and C remain in contact with the surface; the wobbling has either leg B or leg D touching the surface.
Rotate the table 90 degrees. Now legs C and D remain in contact, and the wobbling has either leg A or leg C touching the surface. It follows that somewhere in between there must have been at least one point where all four legs touched the surface.
It seems to me that an attempt to make that more formal would result in what I refer to as a 'Rube Goldberg proof'.
